# How to find out which dependency includes wrong version of Play/Scala in sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to upgrade my Play application from Scala 2.10 to 2.11 and I get conflicting cross-version suffixes:

```
[info] Done updating.
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/E:/Work/MyProject/development/}root:
[error]    com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor _2.11, _2.10
[error]    com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j _2.11, _2.10
[error]    org.scala-stm:scala-stm _2.11, _2.10.0
```

My build.sbt:

```
name := """My Project"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at Path.userHome.asFile.toURI.toURL + ".m2/repository"

resolvers += "scala-sbt.org" at "http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/repo"

resolvers += "scala-sbt.org 2" at "http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/libs-releases"

resolvers += "scala-sbt.org 3" at "http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/plugins-releases"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

EclipseKeys.withSource := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-contrib" % "2.3.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.3.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.4" % "test",
  "io.argonaut" %% "argonaut" % "6.1",
  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.3.0",
   "my.other.project" % "java-artifact" % "2.2.5")
```

In the log from `sbt compile` all of a sudden play_2.10 is resolved:

```
...     
[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpmime;4.0.1 ...
     [info] Resolving org.apache.james#apache-mime4j;0.6 ...
     [info] Resolving play#play_2.10;2.1.5 ...
     [info] Resolving play#sbt-link;2.1.5 ...
     [info] Resolving play#play-exceptions;2.1.5 ...
     [info] Resolving play#templates_2.10;2.1.5 ...
...
```

I am using sbt 0.13.5.

I have had this problem before and solving it was a tiresome process.
Is there any way to know which of my dependencies includes play_2.10? 
Can I get a dependency tree or something similar from sbt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no native way in sbt, but I had a good experience with third parties, particularly https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph.